# How to get a calculated output as mysql column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a calculation by using a mysql query.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT  book_name, 
CASE WHEN  CURDATE()<book_return THEN 0 ELSE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),book_return) END AS DateDifference,
CASE WHEN  DateDifference>0 THEN DateDifference*10 ELSE NULL) END AS TotalFines  FROM tblIssuedBooks order by lastupdated DESC
```

I need to mutiply DateDifference column by 10 if the DateDIfference value is greater than zero.but when I execute this I am getting  `Unknown column 'DateDifference' in 'field list'` as an error.

Can someone show me how to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias in a select which was defined in the same select.  One workaround here uses a subquery:

```sql
SELECT book_name, DateDifference,
       CASE WHEN DateDifference > 0 THEN DateDifference*10 END AS TotalFines
FROM
(
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN CURDATE() < book_return
                   THEN 0
                   ELSE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), book_return) END AS DateDifference
    FROM tblIssuedBooks
) t
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC;
```